# Using CAShaperLayer within COCOS2d

Tags: cocos2d

My class X is interited from CCLayer.

`@interface X : CCLayer`

Then in X, I added an instance variable of type CAShapeLayer.

`CAShapeLayer *_Circle`

I drew the Circle using UIBezierPath. Now if I try to add _circle to self, it gives me error:

`[self addChild:_Circle];`

```
[CAShapeLayer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x916f7f0 * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CAShapeLayer tag]: unrecognized.
```

I also tried typecasting _Circle to (CCNode*) or (CCSprite*) but nothing helped.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `CAShapeLayer` is a class. Try `[_Circle tag];`.

Comment: No, I am not adding [CAShapeLayer tag] myself. It is coming as a run time exception. My statement is [self addChild:_Circle];  The problem is addChild expects CCSprite or CCNode object but CAShapeLayer isn't that. I am not sure how CAShapeLayer can be used inside cocos2d scenes.

Comment: Is that `@interface X : CCLayer` a typo? (CALayer?). And isn't it the other way round, first you create a layer and a sublayer, then you draw a spline between them? See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: CCLayer is a class for layer drawing in COCOS2d. It's not native class. I saw few people suggesting to use CALayer in COCOS2d to animate primitive shapes like circle in my case. I want to programmatically draw a circle and then animate it's drawing on screen. Basically only part of circle will be drawn based on some input value like 60% or 80% and draw should be animated. I have implemented it in CALayer individually but not able to integrate with COCOS2d layers or sceens.